# I'm unable to install samba

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, apt, samba

I'm having trouble with samba that won't install. I did try several time with purge uninstalling and reinstalling but i'm always ending with an error related with a shared library, it seems that the file isn't found but actually the file it's right there.

Here are some troubleshooting steps i did:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u7) ...
Job for smbd.service failed. See 'systemctl status smbd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo systemctl -l status smbd
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-26 20:18:10 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 31528 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Jul 26 20:18:10 raspberry smbd[31528]: Starting SMB/CIFS daemon: smbd/usr/sbin/smbd: error while loading shared     libraries: libntdb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 26 20:18:10 raspberry smbd[31528]: failed!
Jul 26 20:18:10 raspberry systemd[1]: smbd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 26 20:18:10 raspberry systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
Jul 26 20:18:10 raspberry systemd[1]: Unit smbd.service entered failed state.

pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo testparm
testparm: error while loading shared libraries: libntdb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

pi@raspberry:~ $ locate libntdb.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libntdb.so.1
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libntdb.so.1.0

pi@raspberry:~ $ ll /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ |grep libnt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 Jul 11  2014 libntdb.so.1 -> libntdb.so.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    83672 Jul 11  2014 libntdb.so.1.0

pi@raspberry:~ $ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/

pi@raspberry:~ $ ldconfig -p |grep libntdb  
    libntdb.so.1 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libntdb.so.1

pi@raspberry:~ $ ldd /usr/sbin/samba|grep libn
    libntvfs.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/samba/libntvfs.so.0 (0xb6df3000)
    libndr.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libndr.so.0 (0xb6dd2000)
    libndr-samba4.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/samba/libndr-samba4.so.0 (0xb6b78000)
    libndr-standard.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libndr-standard.so.0 (0xb686a000)
    libndr-samba.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/samba/libndr-samba.so.0 (0xb63b6000)
    libnpa-tstream.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/samba/libnpa-tstream.so.0 (0xb6366000)
    libnetif.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/samba/libnetif.so.0 (0xb632f000)
    libndr-nbt.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libndr-nbt.so.0 (0xb615a000)
    libndr-krb5pac.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libndr-krb5pac.so.0 (0xb5fc1000)
    libntdb.so.1 => not found
    libntdb.so.1 => not found
    libnettle.so.4 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.4 (0xb5ba7000)
```

Anyone got some clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added any custom repositories?  Please post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I'm using the default one:
'`pi@raspberry:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'

#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi`